# "Annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration" when using @QueryParam and @DefaultValue from JAX-RS

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am getting the following compilation errors:

```
Error(35,13):  annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
Error(36,13):  annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
Error(38,13):  annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
Error(39,13):  annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
Error(41,13):  annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
Error(42,13):  annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
```

All these error are for `@ParamValue` and `@DefaultValue` annotation from Jersey. I have seen lots of example on the internet and they all said that Jersey allows string class and all the wrapper classes. I don't understand why it's not working here.

```
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/sracows")
public class sracoWebService {

    public sracoWebService() {
        super();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/empdata")
    public String getEmployeeData() throws Exception {
        try {
            @DefaultValue("nationality")
            @QueryParam("nationality")
            String nationality;
            @DefaultValue("experience")
            @QueryParam("experience")
            String experience;
            @DefaultValue("empid")
            @QueryParam("empid")
            String empid;
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use within method parameters like getEmployeeData(@QueryParam("nationality") String nationality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) and [`@DefaultValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) annotations can **only** be placed on *resource method parameters*, *resource class fields* or *resource class bean properties*.

Your annotations are places on *local variables* and that's why you have compilation errors.

### You could...

```java
@Path("/foo")
public class MyResourceClass {

    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    public String myResourceMethod(
        @QueryParam("nationality") @DefaultValue("nationality") String nationality, 
        @QueryParam("experience") @DefaultValue("experience") String experience,
        @QueryParam("empid") @DefaultValue("empid") String empid) {

        ...
    }
}
```

### You could...

```java
@Path("/foo")
public class MyResourceClass {

    @QueryParam("nationality")
    @DefaultValue("nationality")
    private String nationality;

    @QueryParam("experience")
    @DefaultValue("experience")
    private String experience;

    @QueryParam("empid")
    @DefaultValue("empid")
    private String empid;

    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    public String myResourceMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

### You could...

```java
public class ParameterAggregator {

    @QueryParam("nationality")
    @DefaultValue("nationality")
    private String nationality;

    @QueryParam("experience")
    @DefaultValue("experience")
    private String experience;

    @QueryParam("empid")
    @DefaultValue("empid")
    private String empid;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
@Path("/foo")
public class MyResourceClass {

    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    public String myResourceMethod(@BeanParam ParameterAggregator params) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your knowledge